# Store and decode values in "binary" as an integer

Tags: php, math

How is the following system called and what would be an easy algorythm to implement a decoding function for the following scenario?

Imagine we have a permission system with the following values. Each permission node gets a number with the following rules:

- READ = 1
- CREATE = 2
- UPDATE = 4
- DELETE = 8

To clarify: I'll call the permission itself a *permission* and the number assigned for it the *value*. Also, I'll call the sum of all *values* the *level*.

When I want to give a user the three permissions *READ*, *CREATE* and *UPDATE* he would have a level of 7. If I calculate these 7 back, I could definitely say, that this user has these exact 3 roles.

My question is: How is this system named and what would be a good situation to calculate this back, meaning: How can I efficiently find out that 7, for example, is made out of 1, 2 and 4 or that a level of 13 is made of 1, 4 and 8? I have absolutely no idea where to start.

Comment: If you're trying to give people permissions to read, create, update and delete, why not create a table called groups and and assign those groups to the user?  That way you'll know what permissions they have, based on what groups they have, as opposed to what the sum of some integers are?

Comment: The example with the permissions is really just an example. I saw this in some places like NPC behaviour configurations in games or simulations. If you want to have a NPC ignoring red light he would get a 1, if he should race on the streets a 2. If the NPC should do both, he would get a 3. It's just another example. I just wondered how something like this is called and how to implement this in an easy and efficient way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a *bit map* or a *bit mask*. When used to store permissions, it's called a *permission mask*.

To test whether a particular value is set, you can use bitwise operators.

```
$mask = 7;
$perms = array();
if ($mask & READ) {
    $perms[] = "READ";
}
if ($mask & CREATE) {
    $perms[] = "CREATE";
}
if ($mask & UPDATE) {
    $perms[] = "UPDATE";
}
if ($mask & DELETE) {
    $perms[] = "DELETE";
}
echo "Permissions are: " . implode(", ", $perms); // prints READ, CREATE, UPDATE
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for!